# SignlarR 2.0 chat sample ASP.NET app in Xamarin Studio Community 6.1.5

Tags: asp.net, mono, xamarin-studio, signalr-2

I'm trying to run the [Getting Started with SignalR 2.0 and MVC 5 sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-c366b2f3) using Xamarin Studio Community 6.1.5 on Mac OS 10.10.5.

In both Firefox and Chrome, the developer tools show that the request to `/signalr/hubs` finishes and responds with a 200, but the body they show doesn't contain anything. (Chrome reports a response size and time; Firefox doesn't.) I added a `debugger` JavaScript statement to `Chat.cshtml`, but the debugger never breaks in Firefox and only breaks in Chrome when I cancel the page load (i.e., pressing `[Esc]` or hitting the `Stop loading this page`) button next to the URL/search bar.

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            // The rest omitted from the Stack Overflow question for brevity.
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

The example does work in Visual Studio.

Should this example work? If it's possible to make it work, what would I need to do?

Comment: witch jquery version are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.10.2, which is what came with the sample.